# Can we query on Field if its mapping is not defined in ES?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-7

Is it possible to Query on field which is not mapped with order??
***Using Elastic search 7.4***

I've created a index with with only 1 mapping

Index name - test_date_mapping_with_null
Dynamic mapping - False
properties - city -> text.

```
{
  "settings" : {
    "number_of_shards" : 2,
    "number_of_replicas" : 1
  },
  "mappings" : {
    "dynamic":false,
    "properties" : {
        "city" : { "type" : "text" }
    }
  }
}
```

Inserting documents with published_at field

```
POST test_date_mapping_with_null/_doc/1
{
  "city": "NY",
  "published_at": "2022-01-01T06:58:27.000Z"
}
```

```
POST test_date_mapping_with_null/_doc/2
{
  "city": "Paris",
  "published_at": "2022-01-02T06:58:27.000Z"
}
```

```
POST test_date_mapping_with_null/_doc/3
    {
      "city": "Mumbai",
      "published_at": "2022-01-03T06:58:27.000Z"
    }
```

```
POST test_date_mapping_with_null/_doc/4
    {
      "city": "Tokyo",
      "published_at": "2022-01-04T06:58:27.000Z"
    }
```

Mapping looks like this

```
"mappings": {
      "_doc": {
        "dynamic": "false",
        "properties": {
          "city": {
            "type": "text"
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Now Upon Search Query

```
GET test_date_mapping_with_null/_search
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "published_at": {
        "gte": "2022-01-01T00:58:27.000Z",
        "lte": "2022-01-03T23:58:27.000Z",
        "boost": 2.0
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Actual - ES returns all the docs.
Expected - ES should return only Doc 1, 2 and 3 (i.e City -> NY, Paris and Mumbai Doc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your index mapping, currently only includes mapping for the `city` field, it does not have mapping for the `published_at`  field as you have set [`"dynamic": "false"`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic.html) in your index mapping.

This means that `published_at` is stored in Elasticsearch, but this field is not indexed in Elasticsearch. In simple terms, this means that you cannot perform any search on the `published_at` field

Comment: Okay @escoder, then after adding mapping, reindexing required?

Comment: @AbhishekJadav yes, after adding a new field in the index mapping, you have to reindex your data. This will index the data in Elasticsearch (and not just `store`), and enable you to search on that field.

Answer (score 1):

No, You can't query the fields if its not indexed in the Elasticsearch(as you define dynamic:false, it won't be index), you however can see the them as part of `_source` when you get a document using `_search` or by document id.

Either change the mapping from `dynamic:false` to `dynamic:true` or add the field explicitly in the mapping(if you want to have dynamic:false), if you want to query the field.

Answer (score 1):

You can't query on fields which are not specified in mapping and dynamic is set to false . You can only store those fields in _source.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.4/dynamic.html